# Using material ui autocomplete on not triggered when writing async test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am trying to write a test to for my component which uses the Material UI Autocomplete component. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but my test doesn't seem to be triggering the onChange of the Material UI Autocomplete component.

```
  it('should render autocomplete and select a user', async () => {
    searchContact.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      data: {
        value: [
          {
            displayName: 'Jan Travis',
            userPrincipalName: 'JanT@email.uk',
          },
          {
            displayName: 'Jon Test',
            userPrincipalName: '',
          },
          {
            displayName: 'Jay Test',
            userPrincipalName: 'JayT@email.uk',
          },
        ],
      },
    });
    initialProps.activityName = 'some-activity';
    initialProps.testId = 'contact-person[0]';
    initialProps.fromType = 'planning-contact-person';
    const { getByRole } = render(<AutoCompleteUserSearch {...initialProps} />);
    const autocomplete = getByRole('textbox');

    autocomplete.focus();

    await act(async () => {
      fireEvent.change(document.activeElement, { target: { value: 'Jay' } });
    });

    fireEvent.keyDown(document.activeElement, { key: 'ArrowDown' });

    fireEvent.keyDown(document.activeElement, { key: 'Enter' });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(autocomplete.value).toEqual('Jay');
    });
```

Here is what my autocomplete component looks like

```
 return (
<React.Fragment>
  <Autocomplete
    id={props.activityName ? props.activityName : props.id}
    freeSolo
    data-testid={props.testId ? props.testId : 'autocomplete'}
    defaultValue=""
    getOptionLabel={(option) => (typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.displayName)}
    getOptionSelected={(option, value) => {
      return option.displayName === value;
    }}
    filterOptions={(x) => x}
    open={open}
    onOpen={() => {
      setOpen(true);
    }}
    onClose={() => {
      setOpen(false);
    }}
    value={autoCompleteValue}
    autoComplete
    includeInputInList
    options={[...autoCompleteOptions]}
    filterSelectedOptions
    clearOnEscape
    onChange={(event, newValue, reason) => {
      setAutoCompleteOptions(newValue ? [newValue, ...autoCompleteOptions] : autoCompleteOptions);
      if (newValue) {
        setAutoCompleteValue(newValue.displayName);
        if (newValue.userPrincipalName) {
          setSelectUserEmailAddress(newValue.userPrincipalName);
          setUserEmailAddressError();
        } else {
          setUserEmailAddressError('This user does not have an email address');
        }
      }
      if (reason === 'clear') {
        setAutoCompleteValue('');
      }
    }}
    size="small"
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <div ref={params.InputProps.ref}>
        <Input
          type="text"
          label="Search user"
          name={props.activityName ? props.activityName : props.name}
          {...params.inputProps}
          inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Search user' }}
          onChange={(ev) => {
            onChangeHandle(ev.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )}
    renderOption={(option, { inputValue }) => {
      const matches = match(option.displayName, inputValue);
      const parts = parse(option.displayName, matches);
      return (
        <div>
          {parts.map((part, index) => (
            <span key={index} style={{ fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400 }}>
              {part.text}
            </span>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }}
  />
```

The onChange within the autocomplete doesn't seem to be trigged. Not sure if the within the test the keyDown is working properly.

Here is my onChangeHandle function within the Input onChange, which is being called

```
  const onChangeHandle = (e) => {
    setAutoCompleteValue(e);
    if (e !== '') {
      if (e) {
        searchContact(e)
          .then((res) => {
            setAutoCompleteOptions(res.data.value);
          })
          .catch(() => {});
      }
    }
  };
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.